# How to ignore or encode Korean word in python?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a problem when my data have Korean words. I want to output the telephone number, but have some Korean words in my telephone data. This gave me the error`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character` How can I ignore or encode Korean word in python?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('tel.csv',dtype = str)

responses = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    Telephone = row['Telephone']
    responses.append(Telephone)
    
  
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(responses))

df.to_csv('mobile.csv',na_rep='NULL',sep = '|',index = None)
```

Example csv:

```
Telephone
+821099999999
+821088888888
+821077777777
+821066666666
ㅍ
+821055555555
+821044444444
+821033333333
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You have to specify an encoding for the output file. Probably the input file,. too.

Comment: And If you want to ignore `df[~df['Telephone'].str.isalpha()]`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. About encoding solution, I add ```encoding='utf-8-sig'``` in ```df.to_csv``` . And this is work. The ignore solution is work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not the best solution but it works:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', index_col=None)
for i in range(len(df['Telephone;'])):
    if df['Telephone;'][i][0] != '+':
        df=df.drop(index=df.index[i])
print(df)
responses = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    Telephone = row['Telephone;']
    responses.append(Telephone)
    
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(responses))

df.to_csv('mobile.csv',na_rep='NULL',sep = '|',index = None)
```

btw you still need to remove the `;`, somehow when I copied your data table to csv I got this strange `;` but I'm just too lazy to remove it.